# Reach router navigate updates URL but not component

Tags: javascript, reach-router

I'm trying to get Reach Router to navigate programmatically from one of my components. The URL is updated as expected however the route is not rendered and if I look at the React developer tools I can see the original component is listed as being displayed.

If I refresh the page once at the new URL then it renders correctly.

How can I get it to render the new route?

A simplified example is shown below and I'm using `@reach/router@1.2.1` (it may also be salient that I'm using Redux).

```
import React from 'react';

import { navigate } from '@reach/router';

const ExampleComponent = props => {
  navigate('/a/different/url');

  return <div />;
};

export default ExampleComponent;
```

Comment: Hi, have you figured out what was causing this? I am running into same issue regardless of navigate or Link being used. If I refresh the page, then the component renders.

Answer (score 2):

I was running into the same issue with a `<NotFound defualt />` route component.

This would change the URL, but React itself didn't change:

```
import React from "react";
import { RouteComponentProps, navigate } from "@reach/router";

interface INotFoundProps extends RouteComponentProps {}

export const NotFound: React.FC<INotFoundProps> = props => {
  // For that it's worth, neither of these worked 
  // as I would have expected
  if (props.navigate !== undefined) {
    props.navigate("/");
  }
  // ...or...
  navigate("/", { replace: true });

  return null;
};
```

This changes the URL and renders the new route as I would expect:

```
...
export const NotFound: React.FC<INotFoundProps> = props => {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    navigate("/", { replace: true });
  }, []);

  return null;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Could it be that you use **@reach/router** in combination with **redux-first-history**? Because I had the same issue and could solve it with the following configuration of my historyContext:

```
import { globalHistory } from "@reach/router";
// other imports

const historyContext = createReduxHistoryContext({
   // your options...
   reachGlobalHistory: globalHistory // <-- this option is the important one that fixed my issue
}
```

More on this in the [README of redux-first-history](https://github.com/salvoravida/redux-first-history#readme)

Answer (score 2):

The same issue happens to me when I'm just starting to play around with Reach Router. Luckily, found the solution not long after.

Inside Reach Router documentation for [navigate](https://reach.tech/router/api/navigate), it is stated that:

> Navigate returns a promise so you can await it. It resolves after React is completely finished rendering the next screen, even with React Suspense.

Hence, use `await navigate()` work it for me.

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react';
import {useStoreState} from "easy-peasy";
import {useNavigate} from "@reach/router";

export default function Home() {
    const {isAuthenticated} = useStoreState(state => state.auth)
    const navigate = useNavigate()

    useEffect(()=> {
        async function navigateToLogin() {
            await navigate('login')
        }
        if (!isAuthenticated) {
            navigateToLogin()
        }
    },[navigate,isAuthenticated])

    return <div>Home page</div>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use `<React.StrictMode>`, remove it and it should work.

Answer (score -1):

Try and use gatsby navigate. It uses reach-router. It solved my problem.

```
import { navigate } from 'gatsby'
```